# C structs, why use ID after "typedef struct"?

Tags: c, struct

Why use this

```
typedef struct complex
{
  int imag;
  float real;
} comp;
```

Instead of this

```
typedef struct
{
  int imag;
  float real;
} comp;
```

Is the `complex` keyword usable somehow?
I mean, I would not use it later, I would just do:

```
comp myvar;
```

Comment: Source: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-structures

Comment: Consider to add a pointer to this struct, a complex*.